# import product videos from old Magento 2 shop to newer version

Tags: magento-2.1, video, product-video, youtube

One of our clients has had a redesign of his website (and got a total new one, products exported from the old one to the newer one.)

He had a lot of product videos on the old website, which need to be added to the newer one. Since we used a product export, rather then taking the old database, products have a different entity_id now.

I have updated the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` table, so that the video value_id's are linked to the proper entity_id's.

When I check the database, all the videos lead to the correct sku's, so the update of the entity id was done correctly, however no videos are displayed.

Already tried a `reindex, setup:upgrade, static-content` etc

Any ideas what I am missing?